# Exporting MySQL data to Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have been looking for ways to export my data to an Excel spreadsheet. I have tried loads of examples and have been unsuccessful. This is my current code that returns, "Query Failed!". when changing the "ORDER BY" however, the spreadsheet returns the data but loops an error underneath. This is the code ive found and am using:

```
$con = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db_name) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  function cleanData(&$str)
    {
      $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
      $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);

      if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }

    $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-16LE");

    $flag = false;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY field") or die('Query failed!');

    while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) 
      {
        if(!$flag) 
          {
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
            $flag = true;
          }

        array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
     }
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens?
(The same thing happens using mysqli functions too)

Comment: Have you considered using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) and/or [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html)?

Comment: What you are making is actually a CSV (tab delimited) file, not a XLS file.

Comment: Rocket, I've done the same process for creating a csv but I'm getting the same response?

Comment: What do you mean by "but loops an error underneath"?  What error?  Also `"Query failed!"` is not a good message to use when debugging, try using something meaningful like `or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Sorry that wasn't very clear. when I change the select statement to say for example "SELECT * FROM test" the data in the table is displayed but then a error message ----->  "<b>Warning</b>:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\export_data\export.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br /> is displayed underneath for around 30 rows.

Comment: @Andrew: Try changing `while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))` to just `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`

Comment: @Andrew I'm assuming line 28 is `array_walk($row, 'cleanData');` and what I think you're trying to do is calling the `cleanData()` function, yet I think it's not properly formatted and should probably be something to the affect of `array_walk($row, 'cleanData()');`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The warning is talking about `array_values`, so it's `echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";`, I assume.

Comment: Also, you are going to want to use MySQL prepared statements, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @RocketHazmat How is the `cleanData` function supposed to be called, is using `array_walk($row, 'cleanData');` correct? I tend to think it's not correct.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: That's correct :-)  Docs: http://php.net/array_walk

Comment: @RocketHazmat I updated the code, no luck unfortunately with regards to the while loop.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I did have my doubts about it. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Andrew: So let me get this straight: You get a "Query Failed" error? An "array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given" warning? Both?

Comment: @Andrew What if you were to use `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc` ?

Comment: No when the query runs with 'ORDER BY field' I revive a "Query Failed" error. When I edit the query to "SELECT * FROM test" I receive the "array_values() error.

Comment: Using mysql_fetch_array I still receive a "Query Failed!" error.

Comment: What's `field`'s type? What's its real name?

Comment: @geomagas sorry what do you mean, I do not understand.

Comment: @Andrew: `"Query failed!"` is not a good message to use when debugging, try using something meaningful like `or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Well, is it a number? A varchar? a timestamp? How was it defined in the `CREATE TABLE` statement? And is `field` its real name, or just an alias for the sake of the example?

Comment: Ok I have made progress. @Fred-ii- the cleanData function should be left as it is. the mysql_error returned that no database was selected, for some reason the connect function alone was not recognizing the variable $db_name. The data now displays with column numbers but that should be easy to sort out. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: That's a big _Doh_ alright!

Comment: @Andrew: That's why you should *always* check `mysql_error` :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it's always the way sometimes (long day). Just to clear things up I've now redone it to create the file in a CSV format and it works perfectly!